# Trying to add Java 8 Project facet to Eclipse Neon Mac

Tags: java, eclipse

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context
>   was:(profile=_Users_me_eclipse_jee-neon_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.objectweb.asm,3.3.1.v201105211655

I read other reports, which said the solution was to add "/" to the end of any repositories that didn't have them.  I did that, and restarted Eclipse.

Same error.

Note, everything I see refers to this as a Kepler bug.  But I'm on Neon, and 1.8 still isn't one of my Java Project Facet options

Answer (score 1):

The **missing plug-in** `org.objectweb.asm` of version *3.3.1.v201105211655* can be found **in the following update site**:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/maintenance/R201402240820/
```

(Adding an update site: in ***Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Update Sites:*** click ***Add...***)

Comment: Good news, that worked.  bad news, I still can't specify Java 8

Comment: @GregDougherty Are errors or warnings displayed if you create a plain Java 8 project?

Comment: No, it's only trying to create a Java 1.8 Project Facet that causes a problem